# Counting letters in a text and printing the count plus the highest and lowest

Tags: java, arrays

Other than the bad format why cant this just print out them all once. I dont think im storing it in the array right or at all. So If you guys could please help me with where I am in the wrong it would be greatly appreciated

```
import java.util.*;

public class LetCount {

    public static final int NUMCHARS = 26 + 1; //You define

    public static int addr(char ch) {
        return (int) ch - (int) 'A' + 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); // for reading input
        int[] count = new int [NUMCHARS];
        int curIndex = 0;
        int max = 0;
        System.out.println("Enter text to be read");
        while (keyboard.hasNext()) {
            String str1 = keyboard.nextLine().toUpperCase();
            char ch = str1.charAt(curIndex);
            for(curIndex = 0; curIndex < str1.length(); curIndex++) {
                ch = str1.charAt(curIndex);
                if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') {
                    addr(ch);
                    count[ch - 'A']++;
                }

                for (int i = 0; i > 26; ++i) {
                    int highest;
                    highest = count[i];

                    System.out.printf(" %c ", i + 'A');
                    System.out.println("occurred " + count[i] + " times");
                    if (highest >= max) {
                        if (highest > max) {
                            max = highest;
                        } 
                    }  
                }

                System.out.println(max);
            }
        } 
    }   
}
```

Comment: Next time, please format your own code. It is difficult to underestimate the readability.

Comment: Sorry as you can tell Im very new and this was my first post

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues in your code:

- You were calculating string length number of times.
- Your `for loop` reads this: `for (int i = 0; i > 26; ++i) {` It should be `for (int i = 0; i < 26; ++i) {`
- You were printing the entire array string length number of times.
- You do not need to use the function `addr` anymore.

Following is the corrected code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class LetCount {

public static final int NUMCHARS = 26 + 1; //You define

public static int addr(char ch) {
    return (int) ch - (int) 'A' + 1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); // for reading input
    int[] count = new int [NUMCHARS];
    int curIndex = 0;
    int max = 0;
    System.out.println("Enter text to be read");
    while (keyboard.hasNext()) {
        String str1 = keyboard.nextLine().toUpperCase();
        char ch = str1.charAt(curIndex);
        for(curIndex = 0; curIndex < str1.length(); curIndex++) {
            ch = str1.charAt(curIndex);
            if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') {
              //  addr(ch); No need to use this
                count[ch - 'A']++;
            }

        }
        int highest;
            for (int i = 0; i < 26; ++i) {   //you had the < sign wrong here.

                highest = count[i];
                if (highest >= max) {
                    if (highest > max) {
                        max = highest;
                    } 
                }  
            } 
            //print the entire thing only once.
            for (int i = 0; i < 26; ++i) {
                System.out.printf(" %c ", i + 'A');
                System.out.println("occurred " + count[i] + " times");
             }

            System.out.println("Maximum is " + max);
          } 
    }   
}
```